# Koin Dependency Injection - org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

Hello I am working on Android app development and in it a koin dependency injection library is integrated. It is something like below:

```
object Jaimin {
   fun initJaimin(
        application : Application,
        listOf : List<Module>? = null
    ) {


        var moduleList = listOf(
            jaiminAppModelModule, jaiminBleNetworkModule,
            jaiminViewModelModule, databaseModule,jaiminRepositoryModule
        )

        listOf?.forEach {
            moduleList = moduleList + it
        }

        startKoin {
            androidLogger(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Level.ERROR else Level.NONE)
            androidContext(application)
            modules(
                moduleList
            )
        }

    }
```

You can check **startKoin** is implemented there.
I am getting error here in this module:

```
val jaiminRepositoryModule = module {
    single {
        JaiminRepository(get(),get())
    }
}
```

Error:

> Instance creation error : could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.jaimin.sdk.repository.JaiminRepository']: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.jaimin.api.RemoteDataSource'. Check your definitions!
> org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:287)
> org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:257)

What might be the issue?

**Edit:**
Below is the constructor for JaiminRepository class:

```
  class JaiminRepository constructor(
    private var remoteDataSource : RemoteDataSource,
    private var enrollApiInterface : EnrollApiInterface
) {
```

and

Below is the constructor for JaiminViewModel class:

```
class JaiminViewModel(application : Application, private var jaiminRepository: JaiminRepository) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var jaiminEnroll : MutableLiveData<JaiminEnroll> = MutableLiveData()
    var error : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    var inputUserID : ObservableField<String> = ObservableField("")
    var isLoading : ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField(false)
```

and inside **ViewModelModule.kt** :

```
  viewModel {
       JaiminViewModel(get(),get())
    }
```

Comment: When you provide definition for `JaiminRepository`, you'll also need to define singleton or factory instances for it's inner dependencies. I.e. `RemoteDataSource` is not found hence you'll need to create definition for it and then you can use it using `get()` inside repository injection.

Comment: Can you please explain? It looks little bit confusing from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is that you're not providing definitions correctly.

When you write `get()`, that means Koin tries to find relevant dependency for that given scope. If it’s not able to find it, then you'll get error `org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException`.

If you look closely to given error:

> Instance creation error : could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.jaimin.sdk.repository.JaiminRepository']: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.jaimin.api.RemoteDataSource'. Check your definitions! org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:287) org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:257)

You'll see that it gives error on `RemoteDataSource`, hence it was not able to find relevant dependency for that.

---

The solution is to resolve those dependencies via definitions.

Here's how your DI for repository should look like:

```
val jaiminRepositoryModule = module {

    factory {
        RemoteDataSource()
    }

    factory<EnrollApiInterface> {
        // Your bean definition for EnrollApiInterface since you can't create objects for interface
    }
    
    single {
        JaiminRepository(get(), get())
    }
}
```

Same goes for view model dependency:

```
viewModel {
   JaiminViewModel(androidContext(), get()) // Here, android context can be used to inject application class
}
```

Comment: Need to change anything here: ?
 viewModel {
        JaiminViewModel(get(),get())
    }

Comment: Yes, all those `get()` should have it’s own definition that Koin can resolve.

Comment: But its there...already. one is for application context & other is for repository.

Comment: As you can see above JaiminRepository has two values 1. RemoteDataSource & 2. EnrollApiInterface. I have added factory {} for RemoteDataSource, How to add it for interface named EnrollApiInterface ?

Comment: EnrollApiInterface is an interface. While writing factory for it, displays "Required EnrollApiInterface, found Unit"

Comment: You'll need implementer for that interface. You can’t provide definitions for interfaces directly. So, create one implementer and use it on this DI definition. I.e. `EnrollApiInterfaceImpl` class that implements this interface.

Comment: I have created implementer but I have no idea what to return from the method.